# Rear of house has no eves; how do I ventilate and prevent ice dams?

Tags: roof, attic, ventilation, soffit, ice

My home is in St. Louis and it just doesn't stay very warm. I am finding that the heat kicks on a lot just so it can keep up. The house is a ranch on a slab, built in 1960, 1073 square feet. In 2015 the entire home was rehabbed, pretty much every single thing besides the slab, studs, walls, and windows....which are newer vinyl.

The exterior was done this year in 2016 due to hail, roof, gutters, vinyl siding, window wraps and probably more. Anyways, when I had the roof done, I had them put in a ridge vent. I also have gable vents on the house.

I checked in the attic and found that the insulation is very poor; I can see the joists! I have a bid to do the attic blow-in insulation up to an R value of 39. Problem: I have no soffit vents whatsoever. NONE. I guess back in the 60's the gable vents were okay but it does not seem like it's getting good ventilation up there, plus from what I've read, with a ridge vent, you need soffit vents.

Here's the issue, I only have eves on the front of the home. Not the back. So I can add soffit vents to the front myself, no issues, but what should I do about the rear of the home? What I'm trying to prevent is ice dams.

[image: Picture of my house]

Comment: You seem to have posted a picture of the front of the house. The back part with no eaves would appear to be more relevant to your question. Might also want to be a bit closer to the house, for detail.